# A problem involving correlated subqueries

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

The problem at hand, - Get pairs of PC models with identical speeds and the same RAM capacity. Each resulting pair should be displayed only once, i.e. (i, j) but not (j, i). 
Result set: model with the bigger number, model with the smaller number, speed, and RAM.

```
Select a.model,model, speed, hd from pc a
where (a.speed in (select speed from pc where model<>a.model and `
a.speed=speed) and a.hd in(select hd from pc  where a.model<>model and a.hd=hd))
```

I tried numerous ways, this is just one of them, the query resulted in identical models and every model had identical speed.

[image]

Here is database schema:

The database scheme consists of four tables:
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)

Comment: please tag the dbms being used.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
select p1.model model1 
      ,p2.model model2
      ,p1.speed
      ,p1.hd 
from pc p1
join pc p2 on p1.speed = p2.speed 
    and p1.hd = p2.hd 
    and p1.model < p2.model
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked best for me. Hope this helps

```
select distinct (A.model), 
B.model,
A.speed,
A.ram from pc A 
join 
pc B on A.speed=B.speed and A.ram=B.ram where A.model>B.model
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this idea but im not sure it its gonna work, you tell me

```
select a.model, b.model, a.speed, a.hd from model a
left join (select model, speed, hd from model) b on a.speed = b.speed and a.hd = b.hd
where a.model <> b.model
```